# Linker error when compiling boost.asio example

Tags: c++, boost-asio, linker-errors

I am trying to compile a boost.asio [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_server.cpp), but I get the following linker errors: "undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'" and "undefined reference to`__gxx_personality_v0'". I've been searching google for a long time, but nothing helped. Which library do I need to link? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show use the exact compile line?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using `gcc` to link your program. If you use `g++` instead it will link in the required libraries.

For Dev-C++, see FAQ entry: [Dev-C++ uses gcc instead of g++ for linking](http://aditsu.freeunixhost.com/dev-cpp-faq.html#gcclink)

Comment: I read that somewhere, but how do I change the compiler in DevC++? (I forgot to mention, I use that program)

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm on Ubuntu 9.10:

```
$ g++ -o chat_server -c chat_server.cpp
In file included from chat_server.cpp:21:
chat_message.hpp: In member function ‘void chat_message::encode_header()’:
chat_message.hpp:84: warning: format ‘%4d’ expects type ‘int’, \
                     but argument 3 has type ‘size_t’
$ ls -l chat_server*
-rw-r--r-- 1 edd edd 1233608 2010-01-09 08:17 chat_server
-rw-r--r-- 1 edd edd    6244 2010-01-09 08:17 chat_server.cpp
$
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, the new kernel doesn't work with the custom display driver.... I'll test it as soon as I fix it.

Comment: Huh?  The kernel and display have nothing to do with your use of g++.  I simply pointed out to you that the Boost example builds fine.  If you have different header locations, you may need a -I.

Comment: Can you speak up a little? I can't hear you among all the screaming.